# ArenaLib and WSM

Tags: system-modeler

[The WSM documentation states](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/SystemDynamics/SystemDynamics.UsersGuide.Overview.Industry.html) that

> Typical tools for such purposes would include ARENA, and there exists also a Modelica implementation of that tool and modeling methodology, called the ARENALib.

Does anyone know where to find the appropriate library to be used in WSM, how to install and to use?

Answer (score 3):

I affraid this question will be closed due to off topic but, you'll find  Modelica Libraries, i.e. a collection of free and commercial libraries there: 
[Modelica Libraries](https://www.modelica.org/libraries).

**Quote**: This page contains a list of Modelica libraries (both free and commercial) - see the short overview of libraries for details.

ARENALib has a [page](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/DESLib.ARENALib.html) you can contact the author **Victorino Sanz**, if the email is still valid.

Good Luck & Have Fun

**Edit**

See also [DESLib](https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/DESLib) Free library for Parallel DEVS and Process-Oriented Modeling in Modelica.

This library contains four packages that can be used to model discrete-event systems:

- RandomLib can be used to generate random numbers and variates,
  following continuous and discrete probability distributions.
- DEVSLib can be used to model discrete-event systems following the Parallel DEVS formalism.
- SIMANLib can be used to model discrete-event systems following the process-oriented approach. Its functionalities are equivalent to some of the functionalities of the SIMAN modeling language.
- **ARENALib** can be used to model discrete-event systems following the process-oriented approach. Its functionalities are equivalent to some of the functionalities of BasicProcess Panel in the Arena simulation environment.

Or see [DESLib Modelica Library](http://www.euclides.dia.uned.es/DESLib/)
Parallel DEVS and Process-Oriented Modeling in Modelica, Author **Victorino Sanz**